# Access UserList within RoomList Room Object with smartfoxserver pro

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, smartfoxserver

Thanks in advance for reading. I've been trying to figure this out for the past two weeks, been researching heavily and have lots of pieces just need to know how to fit them together.

So I'm using flash and smartfoxserver pro.

I would like to create a lobby, where people can host games, and look for matches.

It's a turn based rpg so I want to be able to sort people by their player rank, or level.

What I would like to do is, create an array that holds the players currently awaiting a match.

I am able to do that with this

```
smartfox.onRoomListUpdate = function(roomList:Object)
{
    roomList_lb.removeAll()
    _global.roomlist = roomList;
    for (var i:String in roomList)
    {
        var room:Room = roomList[i]

        if (room.isGame())
        {
        _root.userArray.push([room.getId(),room.getName(),_global.monLev]);
            createPlayerCard("playerCard",200*quicknum,100+ynum,room.getName(),200, room.getId());
            quicknum+=300;


        }
    }
    roomList_lb.sortItemsBy("label", "ASC")
}
```

I was also able to get the roomList info in the onJoinRoom by using my global roomlist variable I created in the previously shown function.

Is there anyway that I can also cycle through the users within the room object created from the roomlist?

I tried

```
smartfox.onJoinRoom = function(roomObj:Room)
{   
    if (roomObj.isGame())
    {       
            trace("_________________________joining room");
        _global.myID = this.playerId;
        var roomid:Number = roomObj.getId();
        sendValues()
        trace("room id "+roomid);
    }
    else
    {
        trace("roomlist "+_global.roomlist);
        for (var i:String in _global.roomlist)
        {
            trace("lookign in");
            var room:Room = _global.roomlist[i]

            if (room.isGame())
            {

                trace(room.getName() + " (" + room.getUserCount() + "/" + room.getMaxUsers()+ ")-(" + room.getSpectatorCount() + "/" + room.getMaxSpectators() )


                         var roomId:Number  = room.getId()
                 var userList:Object    = room.getUserList()

                            for (var i:String in userList)
                               {
                             var user:User      = userList[i]
                             var uName:String   = user.getName()
                             var uId:Number     = user.getId()
                             trace(uName + " " + uId)
                               }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

This way I was thinking I could get the user variables from within the roomlist room object which will contain the rank, the level, maybe an avatar image. And then store the room id, number, name ect and make a nice movieclip to show all this information as well as a duel button.
Then when people press duel it already knows to go to the room where the other person is waiting for a match.

Trying to be clear, this is my first time posting so forgive any formatting issues, and once again thank you thank you thank you for reading and for your help!

Comment: Hi all, so I posted on smartfoxservers forums and got some great feedback, I decided to pull all users and then use a server side extension to send battle invites!